# Merging commits from branch to master -> odd-looking tree

Tags: git, git-branch

I am a relative beginner at git - I have two branches: `master` and `frontend`. I've recently done something that's messed everything up and I don't know how to fix it. I cannot seem to find a way forward without making it worse - I would appreciate your indulgence.

This is my `gitk --all`:

[image: gitk --all]

Top blue: `stash` WIP on frontend
Second blue: index on frontend.
Red: Local uncommitted changes, not check in to index
Green: Local changes checked in to index but not committed
Yellow: `frontend` and `master` branches
5 blues in a line: These are commits made on `frontend` before yesterday's merge
Tan box: my repo on Github (`remotes/origin/master`)
Bottom green box: the production site (`remotes/production/master`)

#### What happened

Last night I did `git stash` on `frontend` to clear my working tree, then  `git checkout master` then `git merge frontend`.

The merge ran into conflicts, then in an attempt to reverse the merge I ran `git reset HEAD@{1}`, and now I'm here and I don't know what to do to clean this up.

I would ideally like to have my two branches back with their separate dirty working trees (frontend's working tree is stored in stash and master's was merged). Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git reflog` to find out where your `HEAD` was before you did the `git reset HEAD@{1}`. Then reset back to that.

Comment: Amber - thanks - will this undo the merge and result in two separate working trees as before?

Comment: It will undo your reset. If you want to undo the merge as well, you'd need to reset to back before the merge (which should also be shown in the reflog).