# How to fix and merge this git tree?

Tags: git, git-branch

Here's my gitk (improved I think from this question, thank you @amber: [Merging commits from branch to master -> odd-looking tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206976/merging-commits-from-branch-to-master-odd-looking-tree)):

Branch `frontend` is on the left. You can see the tip of `master` and `remotes/origin/master` at the bottom right in yellow.

[image: gitk --all git tree]
I need to do two things which I've been through about 36 hours of trouble for:

1. How can I start adding `frontend`'s commits to master (one by one, 'Adding delayed' first) so I can push them? I don't want to merge the entire branch because there's a lot of code involved and both branches have working trees I'd like not to disturb.
2. I seem to have two identical 'Bulk update' entries around `frontend`, the top/left one with no branch. How can I get rid of the branchless `bulk update` stuff at the top so there's 2 clean branches? I'd like to have it looking like this:

   ```
   |  # frontend
   |  # Bulk update.
   |  # ...commits...
   |  # move this frontend commit to master
   |  |  #master's changes
   |  |  #master, remotes/origin/master, remotes/staging/master
   ```

I really would love to do this myself but the last day and a half of struggling has shown that the slightest inaccuracy in what I enter often results in messing it up more.

Answer (score 0):

You should split your question into two separate SO questions to follow the Q&A format.  That being said:

1. Checkout master and use `git cherry-pick -e <sha>` where `<sha>` is the reference to each checkin in `frontend` you want to add to `master`. So you would use `git cherry-pick -e <sha of 'adding delay'>` first.  You can cherry pick in any order you want so you can arrange the checkins you want from `frontend` in a different order to `master`. See http://technosophos.com/content/git-cherry-picking-move-small-code-patches-across-branches.

   An alternative is to rebase, but this might be a bit more confusing than using cherry-pick if you're not use to the mechanism.  I suggest you experiment with this approach on a clone of your repo first.  You can always undo what I am saying, but you don't want to waste your time figuring out how to do that if you're already pressed for time.

   First checkout `frontend` and then create a new branch `tmp` (because you don't want to actually remove frontend).

   Then do `git rebase -i --onto master master tmp`.  This will bring up an editor to remove and rearrange checkins that will be submitted after the master checkin in any order you want that was in your frontend branch.

   When you are done with that `tmp` will be where you want master so checkout `master` and do `git reset --hard tmp` and remove the `tmp` branch `git branch -d tmp`.

   The Pro Git book has good information on rebase, but I've applied the concepts to your use case. http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html
2. First make sure that the bulk changes listed is actually a duplicate.  You could do `git diff <sha of bulk1> <sha of bulk2>` to see the differences.  If it is the same, or not, the key to removing that from the listing is to remove your stash you gave git at some point. If it isn't a duplicate make sure you decide what to do about the differences before just removing the stash.

   While in a branch do `git stash pop` and if you really don't want what you saved in stash do `git reset --hard HEAD`.  At that point if you rerun your gitk (a refresh wont show this) you'll see those entries in the top left removed.  Your gitk graph shows that stash was indexed off of master, so that is where I would work with the stash, but you would know best in which branch, `master` or `frontend`, you may want to work with it on.

   You could also just use `git stash pop` and submit the changes you're saving and it will go away.  The only reason there is a branch history in your gitk is to show how git knows how to recreate the differences in the stash.  Once you pop that stash it will forget about any ancestry of the stash, it is like rebasing the stash to where you popped it to.

   @Jefromi has a cleaner approach for just removing the stash if you don't need anything from them, these aren't his exact words, but what he suggests:

   Use `git stash clear` to remove all stashes. You could use `git stash drop stash@{n}` to just drop that one. Use `git stash list` to see what n should be.

Comment: This is all mostly correct. You're a bit off on the second question, though. Commits are more than just snapshots - they also include metadata. Those two commits could have identical trees, but different messages (and timestamps). And you left out an important thing: the second version of that commit almost certainly was created by `git commit --amend`; it's important to know that amending a commit creates a new commit, and the old one is left dangling. In this case it's pinned there by the stash that was based on it.

Comment: As for popping the stash: you probably don't want to do that on master, since it's likely you stashed away work that made sense in context of the frontend branch. If its contents are important, you'd probably want to check out frontend before popping it. If you want to throw it away, you can use `git stash clear` to remove all stashes, or `git stash drop stash@{n}` to just drop that one (use `git stash list` to see what `n` should be).

Comment: @Jefromi thanks, I couldn't recall what other things may have changed which would change the uniqueness of the commit.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @Jefromi The stash log graph indicates that the stash was pushed on master so it is unclear to me where they might want to pop it, or not.  I edited the answer to indicate they should be aware of the branch they would want to pop any changes in.  I also added the commands to clear and drop a specific stash.